# Bind dynamic objects to datagridview in c# windows form

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a class like this,

```
public class Item
{
  private string _itemCode=string.empty;
  private string _itemName = string.empty;

  //Dynamic variable to keep custom properties
  private dynamic _customProperties = new ExpandoObject();

  public string ItemCode
  {
    get{return _itemCode;}
    set{_itemCode=value;}
  }

  public string ItemName
  {
    get{return _itemName;}
    set{_itemName=value;}
  }

  private ExpandoObject CustomProperties
    { get { return _customProperties; } }

  //Method to load objects
  publc static List<Item> Load()
  {
    List<Item> itemList = new List<Item>();

    //Create Item objects
     Item itm1 = new Item();
     {
       _itemCode="Code1";
       _itemName="Name1";
     }

     //Create custom properties
     itm1._customProperties.Test1 = "t1";

     itemList.Add(itm1);

     //Add more items as above with the several custom properties

     return itemList;  
 }
}
```

In my windows form I'm getting a Item list and assigning it to the datasource of the datagridview.

```
List<Item> lstItems= Item.Load();

//Add item list to the data grid view

BindingSource bindingSource = new BindingSource();
bindingSource.DataSource = lstItems;

this.dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource;
this.dataGridView1.Refresh();
```

When form runs, grid doesn't show the custom properties I have added to the Item.CustomProperties. How can I change my code to overcome this.

Comment: What kind of output you need update your answer

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Answer (score -1):

Try this

Set

```
bindingSource.DataMember = "Your value";  //
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.aspx

Comment: I don't see DataMember being used in the example. Since you have multiple columns and rows, what is this supposed to bind to?